# Bootstrap Popover getting hidden in browser edges. How to resolve it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-popover

[image]

As shown in the screen shot above, some part of the popover is getting hidden into the browser edges.

Is there any work around to relove this issue.

Comment: move the whole search bar to the left or add some right padding to the popover

Comment: I do not have rights to change the design and can only do alterations on popovers. I tried to add the padding as you said but then It looks a bit ugly when its shown elsewhere. @madalinivascu

Comment: then change the left or right property of the popover

Comment: what do you mean shown elsewhere?

Comment: @madalinivascu I am using a template in the popover and If I am setting the padding for resolving the issue then the changes are happening everywhere. How to set left right property of popover. Pardon for my english

Comment: lol use css selectors to select only that popover

Comment: @madalinivascu is it possible to get the current shown Popover from jquery so that I can set its `left` property manually?

Comment: what do you mean manually?, you can do this with css no need for jquery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105972/discussion-between-vikas-bansal-and-madalin-ivascu).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **container** property. Set it to **body**

Here is the complete documentation
http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/popovers

Comment: can not use agular popovers.

Comment: i have tried setting the `container` but still no luck. its still getting hidden in the edges.

Comment: Ditto here. Container set to 'body' doesn't prevent popovers from running off the edge of the screen.